# Co Existence and Backward Compatibility among SNMP Versions

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

I'm new to working with SNMP. I'm confused with Backward compatibility and Coexistence among different versions of SNMP.

Coexistence among versions is defined in [RFC 2576](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2576.txt) where Proxy and multi lingual implementations are explained.

My question is: How does a device running SNMPv3 agent respond to a SNMPv1 request message? How does the agent respond to a message with a simple community String when Authentication and Encryption algorithms are supposed to be used?

How can agents be configured to be multi lingual? 
Is SNMPv3 backward compatible with v1 and v2? (Will it respond to v1 and v2 queries always?)

Comment: I didn't check this, but it probably should not respond at all, or possibly respond with an error. Disclosing any information would be a huge security problem, if the Agent was configured to use user-based security.

Comment: I've read in varioud books and blogs that SNMP V3 is 'Backward Compatible' with v1 and v2.
https://books.google.co.in/books?id=q9ky8sw8LoAC&pg=PT412&lpg=PT412&dq=snmpv2agent+response+snmpv1+requests&source=bl&ots=mx6OaRL8Q5&sig=XXntgnHZ2VbMMZR5srSSoiEhJB8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=doRxVb_KOcm1uASao4O4CA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=snmpv2agent%20response%20snmpv1%20requests&f=false

What exactly is 'Backward Compatibility'?

Comment: If you set your v3 Agent to use community-based security, then yes, it is completely backwards compatible. But in fact, you would have an insecure solution.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever said SNMPv3 is "backwards compatible" likely meant either (or both):

- That most agents supporting SNMPv3 are multi-lingual agents and will also talk SNMPv1 and SNMPv2c, if configured to do so.
- SNMPv3 uses the same MIB language (SMIv1/SMIv2) as do earlier versions and therefore can supports the same MIB modules with no modifications.

The protocol itself is different between the three versions and are not compatible with each other, but can be translated by proxy (with some exceptions) and share some similarities:

- SNMPv2c is nearly identical to SNMPv1, except for different version number in the encoding, new data type(s), and Get-Bulk requests that are not not supported by SNMPv1.
- SNMPv3 uses all the same data types and PDUs with the same encodings as SNMPv2c but an entirely different message encoding.

> How does a device running SNMPv3 agent respond to a SNMPv1 request
>   message?

A multi-lingual device supporting SNMPv3 and SNMPv1 responds to an SNMPv1 request with an SNMPv1 reply and to an SNMPv3 request with an SNMPv3 reply.

> How does the agent respond to a message with a simple community String
>   when Authentication and Encryption algorithms are supposed to be used?

You can't have a message with a simple community string when authentication and encryption algorithms are supposed to be used because authentication and encryption are features of SNMPv3 and the SNMPv3 message encoding has no field for a community string. It has a user name and fields indicating the authentication and privacy levels of the message and parameters necessary to perform those functions.

> How can agents be configured to be multi lingual?

The standard way would be through appropriate configurations for SNMP-COMMUNITY-MIB, SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB, and SNMP-VIEW-BASED-ACM-MIB tables. For example, no communities configured in snmpCommunityTable? Then it's not going to respond to SNMPv1 or SNMPv2c. In lieu of the standard tables of those MIBs, "how" is going to be be implementation-specific.